# Unable to send FCM messages using Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

We are working on a chat application and using cloud functions for sending data notifications to the devices using the FCM registration tokens. Below is the code:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.createMessage = functions.firestore
    .document('messages/{messageId}')
    .onCreate(event => {
        const db = admin.firestore();
        var newValue = event.data.data();

        var recipient = newValue.recipient_id;
        var msg = newValue.message;
        var sender = newValue.sender_id;
        var senderRef = db.collection('users').doc(sender);
        var recipientRef = db.collection('users').doc(recipient);

        const senderObj = new Promise(
            function(resolve, reject) {
                senderRef.get()
                    .then(doc => {
                        if (!doc.exists) {
                            console.log('No such User document!');
                            reject(new Error('No such document!'));

                        } else {
                            console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
                            resolve(doc.data());
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log('Error getting document', err);
                        reject(err);
                    });
            });

        const recipientObj = new Promise(
            function(resolve, reject) {
                recipientRef.get()
                    .then(doc => {
                        if (!doc.exists) {
                            console.log('No such User document!');
                            reject(new Error('No such document!'));

                        } else {
                            console.log('Document data:', doc.data());
                            resolve(doc.data());
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log('Error getting document', err);
                        reject(err);
                    });
            });

        return Promise.all([senderObj, recipientObj]).then(results => {

            var senderDetails = results[0];
            var recipientDetails = results[1];

            var payload = {
                "data": {
                    "title": String(senderDetails.first_name),
                    "body": String(msg),
                    "recipientId": String(recipient),
                    "senderId": String(sender),
                    "senderImage": String(senderDetails.avatar),
                    "createdTime": String(newValue.created_time),
                    "chatType": "one",
                    "messageId": String(event.params.messageId)
                }
            };

            var options = {
              priority: "high"
            };

            /*
            if (recipientDetails.device_type != "android"){
              payload["content_available"] = true;
              payload["priority"] = "high";
            }
            */

            admin.messaging().sendToDevice(recipientDetails.device_token, payload, options)
                .then(function(response) {
                    console.log("Message sent: ", response);
                })
                .catch(function(error) {
                    console.log("Error sending message: ", error, payload);
                });
        });
    });
```

This in development and was working properly sending notifications to the devices until last week. It first began to delay the messages 5-10 minutes and now we are not receiving any notifications at all. The logs on clould functions say the messages are being delivered successfully :(

Has something changed on Firestore/Cloud Functions recently or is there any issue with the code? Any pointers will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to return the `Promise` from `sendToDevice()`:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(...) // ADDED return
```

Comment: Thanks Bob, this is working with return, but I'm sure it was working without promise return as well until last week! Anyways thanks for your answer.